# Making one list the index of another list in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
list2 = [0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0]
```

My goal is to make `list1` the index of `list2`, such that any floats from `list2` that contain the same index value will be summed as the following:

```
final = [0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 4.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

Since `list1` does not contain the numbers 0 and 4, `final` outputs both index values as zero.

What I've been trying is to use the `zip()` function to combine both `list1` and `list2` into

`new = [(1, 0.0), (2, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 1.0), (3, 4.0), (5, 3.0)]`

This is where I am stuck. I want to implement a for loop that will assign `new[0]` values as the index of a new list, and append `new[1]` to this list. I guess my problem is that I have no clue how format this loop. I'm relatively new to python so any help is much appreciated

Comment: And what problems are you facing implementing this?

Comment: No worries. Please [edit] your question to include this information rather than leave it in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
list1 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
list2 = [0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0]
new_l = {a:sum(i[-1] for i in b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x:x[0])}
final_list = [new_l.get(i, 0.0) for i in range(len(list1))]
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 4.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: This works.  Guess I should get more familiar with itertools.  Thanks!

Comment: @microjrm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do without any external library:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
list2 = [0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0]

new=[0.0]*len(list1)
index_dict={}
for i in zip(list1,list2):
    if i[0] not in index_dict:
        index_dict[i[0]]=[i[1]]
    else:
        index_dict[i[0]].append(i[1])

for i,j in index_dict.items():
    new[i]=sum(j)

print(new)
```

output:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 4.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```